# Why won't my videos from Wowza show up?

Tags: wordpress, wowza, jwplayer6

I'm currently working on changing the theme of a wordpress site that my university uses called the Maine Journal. Each article on the site has a video that accompanies it, and on the old theme we were using called Carton, the videos(using JWPlayer to play) would show up just fine. But when I switched themes, they just show up as `[wowza name = "videoName".mp4]` on the live site. I'm unsure where the disconnect is happening.
    I can confirm that Wowza is working, because when I switch back to the old theme, the videos and the player show up. So I'm almost convinced it's either something in the theme or JWPlayer plugin that is breaking.
    What could be going wrong? If anything, how can I fix it?

Comment: I should mention that the theme I switched to is a version of the "Customizr" theme

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be the shortcode for the player plugin. It's possible that the theme you are using is preventing the javascript or plugin from running. Some Wordpress themes do not allow shortcodes by default. You will need to configure it [by following their tutorial](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/html-entities-shortcodes-featured-pages/).